# How to use a different version of cakephp?

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have downloaded many cakephp versions, from 2.3.1 to 2.3.9, I would like to test my app using different versions.

I know that i need to override /lib directory with the version i want to use. But, is there a more efficient way?

i have:

```
/cakephp/2.3.1
/cakephp/2.3.2
/cakephp/2.3.3
/cakephp/2.3.4
....
```

How can I switch the version of cakephp easily?

maybe link: `/home/example.com/www/lib > /cakephp/2.3.2/lib`

Comment: use symlinks, like you said.

Comment: @joshua.paling I thought there was a different way to do that, maybe using the /Config/bootstrap.php ?

Comment: What is the motivation for testing the app against different versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Overview:**

It's really simple and only  requires changing a path in a single file.

**Details:**

Just keep all your cake versions in a folder above your `app/` directory - something like this:

```
app/
cake/
    cakephp_1_3/
    cakephp_2_1/
    cakephp_2_2_beta/
    cakephp_2_3_9/
```

Then, whenever you want to try a new version, just change the line that sets `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH` in your `app/webroot/index.php` file to the version of CakePHP you want to use.  Example:

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'D:\wamp\cakephp\cakephp_2_3_9\lib');
```

**Notes:**

This also works online - just make sure to change the path to the location on the server instead of your local machine.

I find it VERY helpful to keep CakePHP core files separate like this so you can just update to the latest version easily while allowing to back-step if there are any issues.

Also make sure if you require any Plug-ins that are held within the specific version of cake that you copy them over to the new version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have started using CakePHP from 1.3 stable till the latest 2.4 beta.

I never have multiple versions for my app, but I have successfully upgraded from one version to the new version. This is the only time I need to test my app against different versions of CakePHP.

I am not sure the reason behind testing the app against different versions in your case.

I will first read the migration guide to see if there is any major change. Usually for minor upgrades, meaning from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2, I would skip reading the migration guide because the changes are not huge.

If it is a major upgrade like 2.1 to 2.2, my steps are:

1. Create a separate branch
2. Replace my lib folder with the new version.
3. Refactor any existing app code to accommodate the upgrade after reading the migration guide
4. Refactor my unit tests if necessary
5. Keep repeating 3 and 4 till all tests passed.
6. Now merge back to main branch

For minor upgrades like 2.3.1 to 2.3.2, my steps are:

1. Create a separate branch
2. Replace my lib folder with the new version.
3. Run my unit tests
4. Refactor app code if necessary till all tests passed.
5. Merge back to main branch.

If you are NOT testing against versions because of upgrade, then I guess your idea of using symlinks is good enough.